# como inserir no insert postgres sql where

Tags: postgresql

Estou a inserir dados numa tabela no postgres, acontece que tenho um campos que nao existem na tabela referenciada e logo da erro ao tentar inserir um registo que não existe. Preciso de colocar um `where`...

```
INSERT INTO sexo(id,censo,sexo)
SELECT  "SEXO","CENSO","ABREV"
FROM dblink('dbname=censos2001 host=localhost user=postgres password=admin' ::text,'SELECT   "SEXO","CENSO","ABREV" FROM "SEXO"' ::text,false) 
as tabela_temp("SEXO" varchar, "CENSO" varchar ,"ABREV" character varying)
```

Comment: ESTA RESOLVIDO ADICIONEI UM WHERE NO FINAL